# Test subclass behaviour?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I created a cooperation of 4 classes (Python).

```
class A:
    ## A, B, C are nested classes of A
    class B:
        ...
    class C:
        ...
    class D:
        ...
    ## example methods
    def newB(self):
        return self.B()
    def newC(self):
        return self.C(self.newB())
```

I wrote 60 test-methods in 4 test-cases and this was hard work.

Because B, C, D do not offer much behaviour, the A, B, C, D classes shall be subclassed to add new behaviour.

The Problem:

I wrote much test code to ensure that A, B, C, D cooperate right.
If I subclass A, B, C, D to A2, B2, C2, D2 I will need to test the behaviour of A2, B2, C2, D2 in the same way I tested A, B, C, D.

How do I do this?

1. subclass all unittests every time I create a new subclass of Database?
2. generate the test cases and a suite by a method?
3. ...

What would be your practices to assure that the subclassed Database works correctly and there is no mistake in it?

Given: unittests, the classes of Database and your subclass(es)

Tests that exist now:

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    A = A
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = self.A()
    def test_something(self):
        ...

class MockB(A.B):
    ...
class AWithMock(A):
    B = MockB
class TestAWithMock(TestA):
    A = AWithMock
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = self.A()
    def test_something_new(self):
        ...

class MockB2(A.B):
    ...
class MockC2(A.C):
    ...
class MockD2(A.D):
    ...
class TestWithMock(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_b(self):
        b = MockB2()
        ...
    def test_c(self):
        ...
    def test_d(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Sounds like homework/an assignment to me... Correct me if I'm wrong though...

Comment: and if not, the language is hard to understand, couldn't you put a few more minutes into writing your question so we can understand it?

Comment: wrong, its just the form i gave it. But right - I am doing this at home.

Comment: I will  remove tha domain knowledge in a view minutes to make it more abstract.

Comment: Include your work.  Show what you're trying and what isn't working.

Comment: @Mike It is more how you think I should go on testing the subclasses. There are no yet. But there will be some.

Comment: The notation you're using is a little odd.  Are B, C, and D defined inside of class A or are they subclasses?  Subclasses of A would be defined as `class B(A): ...` and all the class definitions would be indented to the same level.

Comment: This is not a homework/an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import unittest
class TestCaseA(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.thing = A()

    def test_does_x():
        self.assertTrue(self.thing.does_x())
```

Now define a subclass A2:

```
class A2(A):
    ...
```

I would subclass your testcase but only override the `setUp`/`setup` method as the rest of the API of the subclass `A2` should be consistent with `A`.

So your test subclass would be just:

```
class TestA2(TestCaseA):
    def setUp(self):
        self.thing = A2()
```

Comment: what would you do in case of `TestWithMock` ?

Comment: Without seeing some code I don't see any reason that a mock for subclass `A` wouldn't also work for `A2`.  Of course you could set the mock(s) in your `setUp` method as well so that the mocks can vary with each `TestCase`.

Comment: I would also do it this way. Are there other possibilities, too?